# Why do ng-bind-html and $sanitize produce different results?

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

I'm trying to sanitize the content of some text areas, I cannot use `ng-bind-html` because it breaks two way binding (`ng-model` does not work at the same time)

Strangely when I apply `ng-bind-html` to a model it produces a different result to when I use `$sanitize` or `$sce` inside of a directive.

Here's a sample I made up

http://plnkr.co/edit/iRvK4med8T9Xqs22BkOe?p=preview

First text area uses `ng-bind-html`, the second uses `$sanitize` and the third should be the code for the ng-bind-html directive as I ripped out of the AngularJS source code.

`&quot;` is only corrected changed to `"` when using ng-bind-html, in the other two examples it changes to `&#34;`

How can I replicate the results of `ng-bind-html` in my directive - while keeping the two way binding?

```js
angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce',
    function($scope, $sce) {

      $scope.value = 'This in &quot;quotes&quot; for testing';
      $scope.model = 'This in &quot;quotes&quot; for testing';

    }
  ]).directive('sanitize', ['$sanitize', '$parse', '$sce',
    function($sanitize, $parse, $sce) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

          var process = function(input) {
            return $sanitize(input);
            //return $sce.getTrustedHtml(input);
          };

          var processed = process(scope.model);
          console.log(processed); // Output here = This in &#34;quotes&#34; for testing
          $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, processed);
          //element.html(processed);
        }
      };
    }
  ])
  .directive('sanitizeBindHtml', ['$parse', '$sce',
    function($parse, $sce) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

          var parsed = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

          function getStringValue() {
            var value = parsed(scope);
            getStringValue.$$unwatch = parsed.$$unwatch;
            return (value || '').toString();
          }

          scope.$watch(getStringValue, function ngBindHtmlWatchAction(value) {
            var processed = $sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '';

            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, processed)
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">


<body ng-app="sanitizeExample">

  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <textarea ng-bind-html="value"></textarea>
    <br/>{{value}}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <textarea sanitize ng-model="model"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <textarea sanitize-bind-html ng-model="model"></textarea>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is interesting. The `ngModel` directive seems to be causing issues here for you, and setting `priority` won't fix it. In your final example, copying `ngBindHtml`, if you replace `ngModel` with another name (e.g. `bob`, `bob="model"`), it will work. http://plnkr.co/edit/eVA9lvMmwOcWKL1B2fjM?p=preview .  Similar for your second directive, except it requires a few other minor changes re: parsing.

Comment: Curious to hear a full answer from somebody with more experience with, or the time to dig into `ngModel` directive. If that doesn't happen, I'll dig into that source when I have a bit more time :) . For the time being, as I mentioned, updating to another attribute works for your other directive, too http://plnkr.co/edit/lVH1IQAhMfAot116xfiM?p=preview

Comment: I will have to see what I can dig up on `ngModel` when I have a chance. It's a shame changing the attribute doesn't allow two way binding to function still!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out like we would expect, the sanitation service is returning the same result. Placing a breakpoint inside the [ngBindHtmlDirective](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L202), We can step in and see what is happening. We dive in and examine the values inside the [$SanitizeProvider](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L149-L153). The value of `buf` that will be returned back to the ngBindHtmlDirective is:

> This in &#34;quotes&#34; for testing

The exact same as we get for calling $sanitize, so what's the real difference? The real difference is between a textbox's innerHTML and value. View this [example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iHbDy8jI6O89RjPBtVPy?p=preview). You can see the difference between calling the two different methods, with the different ways of escaping a double quote. I didn't go digging though the w3 spec or the browser code, but I assume the innerHTML assignment is doing additional work under the hood of creating a documentFragment, grabbing it's textContent, then assigning that to the textbox's value. Obviously value is just grabbing the string and inserting it as is.

---

So what's the problem with your directives? I see that `element.html(processed)` is in a comment, but uncommenting it doesn't have an affect. Well the truth is that it does work for a split second! Stepping though with the debugger, the value of the textbox is correctly set, but then a $digest cycle gets fired and immediate changes it! The truth is the ngModelDirective is getting in the way, specifically it's the [$render function of the baseInputType](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1131). We can see in the code it is using the `element.val` method.

How can we fix this in the directives? Require the ngModelController and override its $render function to use `element.html` method instead ([example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xUgzPWUkoMZ68YjlnmBf?p=preview)).

```
// Add require to get the controller
require: 'ngModel',

// Controller is passed in as the 4th argument
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

// modify the $render function to process it as HTML
ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
    element.html(ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue) ? '' : ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
};
```