# Do I still need ngSanitize if I'm not going to use ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs

My questions really are:

1. Do I still need ngSanitize if I'm **NOT** going to use ng-bind-html? If yes, why?
2. Is it used anywhere else other than ng-bind-html?
3. Does ngSanitize affect the way DOM input elements affect their underlying model through ng-model?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes you will. ng-bind-html will use `$sanitize` and this requires you to have ngSanitize available.

2) Probably

3) This does not work with ng-model ([Why do ng-bind-html and $sanitize produce different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656190/why-do-ng-bind-html-and-sanitize-produce-different-results))